# I want to open a new ViewController through UITableViewRowButtonAction

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, uitableviewrowaction

I have a `UITableViewRowAction` so when I slide there are 3 options from which I can choose. If I click on the `Call` button I want a new `ViewController` to pop over the whole screen. And if I click on a button inside the new `ViewController` *I want it to be dismissed*.

On click on the Call button opens a ViewController as popover
[image: My UITableViewRowAction]

This opens after my click on the button and this should dismiss on click on the bottom x-button
[image: My ViewController as popover]

This is my code

```
func buttonToDismiss (sender: AnyObject) {

    self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let callButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Call", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
        self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(
            self.tableView,
            commit: .delete,
            forRowAt: indexPath)

        let vc = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 62/255.0, green: 70/255.0, blue: 80/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover


        let declineButton = UIButton()
        declineButton.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 484, width: 75, height: 75)
        declineButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 36/255.0, green: 44/255.0, blue: 55/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        declineButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
        declineButton.layer.cornerRadius = declineButton.frame.size.height / 2
        declineButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        declineButton.clipsToBounds = true
        declineButton.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
        declineButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonToDismiss:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        vc.view.addSubview(declineButton)
        let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController!
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

        var cellAbsolutePosition = cell.superview!.convert(cell.frame.origin, to: nil)
        cellAbsolutePosition.x = cell.frame.width - 60
        popover.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: cellAbsolutePosition, size: cell.frame.size)
        popover.sourceView = tableView

        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    })
```

I know that the code is I think very chaotic but I'm not yet very good at programming apps.

I appreciate any help and thank you in advance for your efforts.

Comment: Please describe your query in a little more detail... Uploading images and specifing your need would help better for us to guide you on the point.

Comment: Above is my current code and I have a view controller with popOverPresentation which looks similar to the one on the picture. But I want to add a button to the view controller so it disappears when I click on the button to make the view controller disappear and my parent view controller shows up again. I upload two more pictures to give a better insight what I mean

Comment: Why are you using simple `UIViewController`? Create a new `ViewController` in `xib/storyboard` instead, create an `@IBAction` and wire it to the dismiss button.

Comment: I don't understand how I can connect the ViewController in storyboard so the UITableViewRowAction opens it first.

Comment: you are actually confusing things. What you are trying to do is very easy and straightforward. I'll post an answer shortly that'll explain the matter.

Comment: @devtimg have a look at my answer below. Hope it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: code uploaded..let me know. if you need anything about my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead of what you are doing:

1. Create the `ViewController` that you want to present when `call action` is selected
2. Place the `dismiss` button on that `ViewController` and wire it to an `IBAction`
3. When user selects `call action`, instantiate that `ViewController` from the `storyboard` and simply present it

Here's a simple example:

Say this is the `ViewController` that you want to present when call action is triggered
[image: View Controller to be presented]

Instantiate and present the `ViewController` in the `call action`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var rowActions = [UITableViewRowAction]()

    let callAction = UITableViewRowAction.init(style: .default,
                                               title: "Call") { (action, cellPath) in
                                                //instantiate the view controller with storyboard ID
                                                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
                                                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: { 

                                                })
    }

    rowActions.append(callAction)

    return rowActions
}
```

Just wire up your button with the `IBAction`

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: DetailDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly smooth.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but it says: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score. So I think I just have not enough reputation to do so. Sorry for that.

Comment: Haha no issues it's absolutely fine 

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:** Tested in Swift 3.

**MainVC:**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let callAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "Call") { (UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "callSegue", sender: self) 
    }

    let videoAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "Video") { (UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void in
    }

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "Delete") { (UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void in  
    }

    callAction.backgroundColor = .blue
    videoAction.backgroundColor = .green
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return [deleteAction,videoAction,callAction]

}
```

**DestVC**

```
@IBAction func dissmissButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but the answer above already worked for me. But I am thankful for your efforts